# Client can't connect to socket.io namespace

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm developing an application using socket.io and nodeJs. While I'm developing on my local machine I'm able to connect to namespaces properly. However, when I deploy the application to an Amazon EC2 instance only the root (`/`) namespace is connected.

Server code:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  console.log('root called');
  socket.on('test', function() {console.log("ROOT")})
});

var namespace = io.of('/namespace');
namespace.on('connection', function(socket) {
  console.log('namespace called');
  socket.on('test', function() {console.log("NAMESPACE")});
});
```

Client code

```
var socket2 = io.connect('/namespace', {
  transports: ['websocket'],
  upgrade: false
});

setTimeout(function() {
    socket2.emit('test');
},3000);
```

When I start up the NodeJS app on the EC2 instance and look at the logs the only thing logged is: `root called`. The namespace never gets called/connected to. So the connection get's made, but the client is only connected to the root namespace.

However, when I do the same with the app running locally, it connects to both root and the namespace.

```
root called
namespace called
```

Then every 3 seconds:

```
ROOT
NAMESPACE
```

Is this an issue with the EC2 instance? Or is there something else going on here?

Thanks in advance.