# Socket.io client can't connect to namespace of server in Docker Swarm

Tags: docker, socket.io, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I am developing an ExpressJS & Socket.io server. While running it locally or with docker-compose my test client can connect to requested namespace, but when I deploy it in a Docker Swarm (even if it is my dev machine itself) I get the connect event on client side but not on server side.

Code for handling server side connections:

```js
  app.wsEngine.socketio
    .of(/^\/\w+$/)
    .on("connect", (socket) => console.log('Connected'));  // Called only locally and with compose
```

Client:

```js
const io = require('socket.io-client');

socketio = io("http://localhost:8282/1", { path: "/tg/ws" });
socketio
  .on("connect", () => console.log("Connected!")); // Always called
```

Compose file (used for both compose and deploy):

```yaml
version: "3.3"

networks:
  tg_live:
    driver: overlay

services:
  tg:
    image: app:alpha1
    networks:
      tg_live:
        aliases:
          - tg.tms.asts.com
    ports:
      - "8282:8080"
```

I don't know what I could test. I saw there is [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46840008/client-cant-connect-to-socket-io-namespace), but it received no help.